# Why I get an error message in TYPO3 Extbase on the second time?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I write an extension and use TYPO3 8.7 extbase. When I clear all cache my extension works only by the first Page visit, the second page visit get this error message:

> Cannot create empty instance of the class "Pit\PitExt\Domain\Model\Settings" because it does not implement the
>   TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\DomainObjectInterface.

Where is the Problem? On the first Visit it implement the interface, on the second time not?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: *Does* `Settings` implement `DomainObjectInterface`? Did you flush all caches including Opcache?

Comment: Yes. All Caches in install Tool. The Class extends from \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity with extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject and this implements DomainObjectInterface

Comment: OP posted that was resolved as an upper/lower case issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake. I had an upper / lower case problem. It is not "Pit\PitExt\Domain\Model\Settings" its "Pit\Pitext\Domain\Model\Settings". Now it works.